# static function in c

Tags: c, static

I thought that a function in C which is declared static is only visible in the file were i defined it. In the following example the static var is visible in another file. im not quite sure if it is because of the include:

main.c:

```
#include "test.c"

int main() {
    test();
}
```

test.c:

```
static void test() {
    // do something here
}

void foo() {
   // do something different here
}
```

if it's only working with a header file isn't it totally useless then? If i want to hide a function then i don't mention it in the header file?!

Comment: Yes, it's because of the include. You should include only header files, `.h`.

Comment: @jweyrich: Really? The preprocessor knows nothing about symbols, it just parses tokens consisting of chars. Could you explain how #including a c file is different from pasting its contents directly?

Comment: @flix please try to include only *.h files not *.c files.

Comment: @K-ballo: it's a convention, SHOULD != MUST NOT. I strongly advise that any C programmer SHOULD follow this convention to make other programmer's lives a lot easier.

Comment: Header files end in .h (i.e. not code)

Answer (score 7):

`#include` is a preprocessor directive. When the preprocessor (that runs before compiling) sees it, it will copy the contents of the included file over there. So you end up with it in the same file.

> if its only working with a header file isnt it totaly useless then? if i want to hide a function then i dont mention it in the header file?!

Sure, but not mentioning it in the header file won't "hide" it. The header file is not compiled, if you place your prototypes there it acs as a clue to the compiler.

The advantage of static functions is that they won't be visible outside the file —in the sense that it won't be global in your object file. This allows you to use in other files the same symbol (name) for another thing, without a conflict.

Answer (score 5):

A function in C which is declared static is only visible in the translation unit in which is included, that means that the symbol does not get exported. It has nothing to do with files, but with translation units. In your case there is a single translation unit which is main.c, which includes the contents of another file so defining main, test and foo; main and foo will get exported, while test won't.

Answer (score 1):

If `main.c` and `test.c` were separate *translation units*, you would be correct.  However, by including the text of `test.c` directly into `main.c`, you've created a *single* translation unit, so the static function is visible to `main`. It behaves *as though* you had written it all as one file.

You do not want to `#include` files containing variable or function *definitions*; this is a good way to run into multiple definition errors at compile or link time.  Instead, the contents of `#include` files should be limited to type definitions, non-defining variable declarations and function declarations.

You could create a file `test.h` as follows:

```
#ifndef TEST_H  // include guard; prevents this file from being processed
#define TEST_H  // more than once per translation unit

void foo();     // declaration for foo; this is the only function we're exposing

#endif
```

then rewrite `main.c` as

```
#include "test.h"

int main(void)
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

You would then compile `main.c` and `test.c` separately and then link the resulting object files to create your executable:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c test.c
gcc -o test main.o test.o
```

At this point you will get a linker error along the order of "undefined reference", since the symbol for `test` hasn't been exported.